# Javascript setTimeout - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, timeout

This is my original code:

```
Viewport = {
    rotate: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.startRotate();
        }, 1000);
    }    

    startRotate: function () {
        console.log('in')
    }
}
```

When i tried running the setTimout like:

```
setTimeout(this.startRotate(), 2000);
```

It failed because this way the code in setTimeoout runs instantly..

And In my original code I get "undefined is not a function".

Why is that?

Comment: `this` is in the context of your anonymous function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Viewport = {
    rotate: function () {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.startRotate();
        }, 1000);
    }    

    startRotate: function () {
        console.log('in')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to fix it is using [`Array.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which returns a new function which will be have context set to necessary object:

```
var Viewport = {
    rotate: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.startRotate();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    },
    startRotate: function () {
        console.log('in')
    }
};

setTimeout(this.startRotate, 2000);
```